# Converting character array to int with atoi gives a different value

Tags: c++, c++11

Trying to convert a character array to int data type in C++11. Why is the `int` value `i` different than the character array `value`? Is this because `51,093,843,802` is greater than `2,147,483,647`?

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    char value[] = "51093843802";
    printf("%s\n", value);
    int i = std::atoi(value);
    printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

**Output:**

```
51093843802
-445763750
```

Comment: You want `int64_t`, not `int`.

Comment: Knowing what data type is of what size always helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said, the value `51093843802` can't (usually) fit in [`int`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types), and overflowing a signed integer is [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) (and thus a huge no no) in C++.

You need to use `long long int` (or just `long int` will do if you're on [a system where that's 64 bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    char value[] = "51093843802";
    std::cout << value << '\n';
    long long i = std::stoll(value);
    std::cout << i << '\n';
}
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> 51093843802
> 51093843802
> ```

Notice that I changed `i`'s datatype to be `long long`, `std::atoi` to [`std::stoll`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) and `printf` to [`std::cout`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout), to be more in line with C++ best practises.

Answer (score 1):

`int` is too small to store `51093843802` ([range of values](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types)). Use `atoll` (to long long) and replace i's type to `int64_t`:

```
char value[] = "51093843802";
printf("%s\n", value);
int64_t i = std::atoll(value);
printf("%ld\n", i);
```

Using `long` with `atol` is not safe because on Windows `long` size is 4 bytes even on 64bits system.

Comment: `atoll` still causes undefined behaviour if the result is out of range, so it would be a good idea to use `stoll` instead, which throws if the result is out of range.

Comment: or `strtol(l)` if working with C-style strings and error handling